# Validation in excel where names are listed in the ComboBox but Id is put into the cell

Tags: excel, validation

[image]

In the image above I want to set the language of a person. I can do a validation with the Id-s but I want to display the language names (English, German, Spanish) in the ComboBox but after selection I want the language id in the cell.

It seems I can not do this with simple "Data / data validation". Am I right?

I could select the language name with data validation and after that I could determine the language id from it. This is not I want because the name should depend on the id and not the other way.

I tried to use ComboBox (form control), which returns the index of the selected element, from that index I can determine the Id but it seems silly that I have an index of the language and the id of the language.

SOLUTION BASED ON COY's ANSWER

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Persons[LanguageId]")) Is Nothing Then
        If VarType(Target.Value) = vbString Then
            Position = Application.Match(Target.Value, Range("Languages[Language]"), 0)
            Target.Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("Languages[Id]"), Position)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot think of better choice...you may really need some VBA for this and turn your workbook .xlsm

The key idea is to add handling for Workbook_SheetChange in ThisWorkbook

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 7 Then
    'this example simply take Column G
    'given you have more knowledge on your workbook, you should have better condition here
        If Not IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
            Target.NumberFormat = """" + Target.Value + """"
            Target.Value = WorksheetFunction.Match(Target.Value, Range("LangTable[Language]"), 0)
            Target.Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("LangTable[Id]"), Target.Value)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

To do this in VBA, there are a few different setups to choose.

1. set and display the value as the id (remove the NumberFormat change from my sample code)
2. keep the value as the language name, only display as Id
3. like my sample code, set the value as the id, display the language name